# HI I am unable to do click on SVG image

Tags: angular

HI I need click on svg plus icon image. Can we do click on Svg Image ??

Thanks In Advance !!

```
 <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="add-more-details-text" onclick="alert(1)">
   <object _ngcontent-c1="" data="../../../assets/images/create-account-add- 
   plus.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
 </object> 
 </span>
```

Comment: This looks likes the transpiled code, share your angular code and the issue you are facing. The onclick handler is there and should work.

Comment: @RobertLongson pointer-events:none will make him be unable to click it.

Comment: @Talg123 his onclick is on the span, I assume he wants that to go off and not be swallowed by the object. The question is somewhat unclear though.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes I agree question is not clear.

Comment: @Robert Thanks!!! 
pointer-events: none worked to me 

@ Talg123  if we do angular (click) or onclick on svg image it is not working .. click is working only around svg image but not on svg image .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you actually don't want the SVG image to handle clicks you want the span that contains it to get the clicks. In that case you need to turn off the object tags pointer-events handling so add

```
pointer-events: none;
```

as a CSS style for the object tag.